# QT Data Visualization in ROS Workspace Issue

Tags: qt

I am trying to visualize point cloud data in the ROS Workspace.
From what I've learned QT Data visualisation is available only in QT 5. 
But ROS Workspace is not available in QT 5. It is availabe only in QT 4.8.

Is there any way I can visualize data in ROS Workspace in QT 4.8?

Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us more: which ROS version, which OS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which type of `ROS` version you have or which type of OS you have but hopefully this should get you started or at least provide some suggestions on your project.

There is the possibility to install a `Qt` version with `ROS` plugins. In [this link](https://rosindustrial.org/news/2018/5/31/new-release-of-the-ros-qt-creator-plug-in) you will find the instructions for the installation. 
Also do you already have a `Qt` version installed? If so you may want to consider a different folder to keep the installation files just not to create any conflicts between the `Qt` version and the `Qt` version with `ROS` plugins.

It is possible to visualize a `ROS` workspace in `Qt` if you install that version. Also as you see from the print screen below the `Qt` has several possibility for you:

[image: print screen below]

Or even creating your own node such as:

[image: node_from_ws]
you can also create your own `catkin_ws` leveraging the power of the plugins.
Additionally for the point clod data you could use the following `ROS` [message](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud.html) that is included inside 'sensor_msgs` tools.

There are several useful messages you could leverage from your side such as:

```
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
```

Hope that was helpful for your project.